# Laravel Nova + Spatie Media library

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova, laravel-medialibrary

Trying to use Laravel Nova with Spatie Media Library. I created upload field like this:

```
Image::make('Logo')
        ->store(function (Request $request, $model) {
            $model->addMediaFromRequest('logo')->toMediaCollection('manufacturers');
        }),
```

Seams ok, but Nova still trying to save file name to "logo" column in manufacturers table.

Original excample to customize this field was:

```
File::make('Attachment')
    ->store(function (Request $request, $model) {
        return [
            'attachment' => $request->attachment->store('/', 's3'),
            'attachment_name' => $request->attachment->getClientOriginalName(),
            'attachment_size' => $request->attachment->getSize(),
        ];
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a work around by setting an empty mutator on the model. In your case it would be:

```php
class Manufacturer extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasMediaTrait;

    public function setLogoAttribute() {}

    //...
}
```

Here's an example of my entire implementation. Note that currently with Nova 1.0.6, the `preview()` method is not working, it's returning the `thumbnail()` url.

*App/GalleryItem*

```php
class GalleryItem extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasMediaTrait;

    public function setImageAttribute() {}

    public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null)
    {
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumbnail')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 64, 64);

        $this->addMediaConversion('preview')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 636, 424);

        $this->addMediaConversion('large')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CONTAIN, 1920, 1080)
            ->withResponsiveImages();
    }

    public function registerMediaCollections()
    {
        $this->addMediaCollection('images')->singleFile();
    }
}
```

*App/Nova/GalleryItem*

```php
class GalleryItem extends Resource
{
    public static $model = 'App\GalleryItem';

    public static $with = ['media'];

    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            Image::make('Image')
                ->store(function (Request $request, $model) {
                    $model->addMediaFromRequest('image')->toMediaCollection('images');
                })
                ->preview(function () {
                    return $this->getFirstMediaUrl('images', 'preview');
                })
                ->thumbnail(function () {
                    return $this->getFirstMediaUrl('images', 'thumbnail');
                })
                ->deletable(false);
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why download link is disappeared using these codes?

Answer (score 3):

As with Nova 3 (and Laravel 8) you need to return `true` from the `fillUsing` or `store` method:

```php
File::make('Attachment')
    ->store(function (Request $request, $model) {
        $model->addMediaFromRequest('logo')->toMediaCollection('manufacturers');

        return true;
        // This will tell nova that you have taken care of it yourself.
    })
```

As soon as you return anything but `true` nova will assume, that it needs to save something to the database. This leads to an error if the field does not exist in db (as to expect with spatie-medialibrary) or it will overwrite your precious data if the field exists but serves another purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Nova allows you to return `true` from the callback to indicate that the processing is complete and that it shouldn't set any attributes itself.

This is the code that runs the callback:

```
protected function fillAttribute(NovaRequest $request, $requestAttribute, $model, $attribute)
{
    //...

    $result = call_user_func($this->storageCallback, $request, $model);

    if ($result === true) {
        return;
    }

    if (! is_array($result)) {
        return $model->{$attribute} = $result;
    }

    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        $model->{$key} = $value;
    }
}
```

So either `true` or any empty array will achieve the same thing, but personally feels clearer to do the former.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Image::make('Logo')
        ->store(function (Request $request, $model) {
            $model->addMediaFromRequest('logo')->toMediaCollection('manufacturers');
        return [];
        }),
```

Maybe returning an empty array prevent nova from saving the name.